# Trrying to make a wallet system for myself which updates per user input through a python-mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql

Im new to python and sql so expect some pretty rookie mistakes, anyways here's the code:

```
import mysql.connector
mycon=mysql.connector.connect (host='localhost', user='root', passwd='****', database='wallet')
cursor=mycon.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from wallet')
print("My Wallet")
crnt=cursor.fetchone()
c=int(''.join(map(str,crnt)))
while True:
    a=input("To show current savings, press 1 \n To add money, press 2 \n To take money, press 3 \n To exit, press 4 \n Enter your choice: ")
    if a=='1':
        print(c)
        continue
    elif a=='2':
        rcvd=int(input("Enter the money recieved : "))
        ad=rcvd+c
        print(ad)
        upadd="UPDATE wallet SET Money=ad"
        cursor.execute(upadd)
        mycon.commit()
        continue
    elif a=='3':
        gne=int(input("Enter the money spent : "))
        sub=c-gne
        print(sub)
        upsub="update wallet set Money=sub"
        cursor.execute(*upsub)
        mycon.commit()
        continue
    else:
        break
mycon.close()
```

Everything works just fine till the execute part, where it shows this error

`TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 27 were given`

Can someone help?
(edited)

Comment: As per the error, it is saying that you are passing non-integer value for the money column. Please check it and rectify it.

Comment: I corrected that error, by removing the quotes on ad and sub but now its showing another error :  `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ad' in 'field list'`

Comment: I fixed that too, by adding an * to upadd and upsub but now its showing yet another error, `TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 27 were given`